# what are the difference between cloudera BDR HDFS replication and snapshot

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, cloudera

Testing Cloudera 5.15.1 BDR, a little bit confused on HDFS replication vs. HDFS Snapshot.
using BDR, it will replicate HDFS data and Snapshot to the DR site. What exactly are the difference between HDFS Replication vs. Snapshot?
How does HDFS replication with BDR works internally?

Comment: Did you already look at https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-15-x/topics/cm_bdr_about.html?

Comment: Yes, I did check Cloudera document on BDR. But I still yet to get the essential difference between HDFS Replication vs. Snapshot. Since Replication runs on batches, my understanding is that it's the same like snapshot to DR site.  snapshot can be replicated to DR site as well. If replicating both HDFS replication & Snapshot to DR site, is there any difference?

Answer (score 1):

> snapshots allow you to create point-in-time backups of directories or the entire filesystem **without actually cloning the data**

Replicas, on the other hand are data copies.

Regarding how they work, snapshots to me sound like it's just a Namenode backup - the file metadata at a point in time is frozen.

Replication on the other hand could be applied on a schedule using Distcp, but Cloudera could add some extra tooling around it